# Parent uses-feature android.hardware.location

Tags: android, android-manifest, uses-feature

Does the usage of parent feature (for `uses-feature` tag) in AndroidManifest.xml mean the same as all enabled child features?

For example, is the following block

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
```

equal to

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the usage of parent feature (for uses-feature tag) in AndroidManifest.xml mean the same as all enabled child features?

It does not. The 2 blocks you show are not equal. The opposite is true however: if you declare *android.hardware.location.gps*, it is automatically implied that you also declare *android.hardware.location*

See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features) for more info. I copied relevant parts and emphasized in bold:

> *android.hardware.location*
>   The app uses **one or more features** on the device for determining location, such as GPS location, network location, *or* cell location.

> *android.hardware.location.gps*
>   The app uses precise location coordinates obtained from a Global Positioning System **(GPS)** receiver on the device.
>
> **By using this feature, an app implies that it also uses the android.hardware.location feature**, unless this parent feature is declared with the attribute android:required="false".

> *android.hardware.location.network*
>   The app uses coarse location coordinates obtained from a *network-based geolocation* system supported on the device.
>
> **By using this feature, an app implies that it also uses the android.hardware.location feature**, unless this parent feature is declared with the attribute android:required="false".